# How to add navigation link to different buttons on the menu in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, menu

I want to add navigation path to all my buttons in the left menu (which is not the main menu).

I am getting the menu items name as @Input. I have created a dictionary for all the items name and their navigation path.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row-styles" id="elements" *ngFor="let item of elements">
    <button *ngIf="(item.action !== NO_ACCESS )" class="inner-children" routerLinkActive="active" id="inner-children" 
    [routerLink]="">
     <span>{{item.resource}}</span>   
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is the TS file

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'apm-menu-resource',
    templateUrl: './menu-resource.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu-resource.component.less']
})
export class MenuResourceComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() public elements = [];

    constructor() {
        const menupath = new Map<string, string>();

        menupath.set('General', '/Adigem/config/general');
        menupath.set('Messaging', '/Adigem/config/messaging');
        menupath.set('Server', '/Adigem/config/email/server');
        menupath.set('Alerting', '/Adigem/config/email/alert');
        menupath.set('Network', '/Adigem/config/network');
        menupath.set('Inventory', '/Adigem/config/inventory');
        menupath.set('External port', '/Adigem/config/snmp/external-port');
        menupath.set('Cloud Data', '/Adigem/config/clouddata');
        menupath.set('Performance', '/Adigem/config/Performance');
        menupath.set('CFG', '/Adigem/config/cfg');
        menupath.set('System', '/Adigem/config/system');

        console.log(menupath);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        
    }
}
```

I want to know what to add in the router link in the HTML so that it navigates to the proper menu item.

Comment: Can you please share your elements Array

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `elements` array, that's being passed to the component, you could simplify things a lot - you just add the target path to each of the items and your `MenuResourceComponent` won't have to deal with any path-related logic.
From your snippets I infer that there is a `resource` property, which is the element's title. If so, the `elements` array can be modified like this:

```
elements = [
  {resource:'General', path: '/Adigem/config/general'},
  {resource:'Messaging', path: '/Adigem/config/messaging'},
  ...
]
```

and then in the template:

```
<div class="row-styles" id="elements" *ngFor="let item of elements">
  <button *ngIf="(item.action !== NO_ACCESS )" class="inner-children" 
   routerLinkActive="active" id="inner-children" 
   [routerLink]="item.path">
   <span>{{item.resource}}</span>   
  </button>
</div>
```

However, if you have no other options and need to `menupath` map, then you can make it a class field:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'apm-menu-resource',
  templateUrl: './menu-resource.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-resource.component.less']
})
export class MenuResourceComponent{

  @Input() public elements = [];
  menupath = new Map<string, string>();

  constructor() {
    this.menupath.set('General', '/Adigem/config/general');
    this.menupath.set('Messaging', '/Adigem/config/messaging');
    this.menupath.set('Server', '/Adigem/config/email/server');
    this.menupath.set('Alerting', '/Adigem/config/email/alert');
    this.menupath.set('Network', '/Adigem/config/network');
    this.menupath.set('Inventory', '/Adigem/config/inventory');
    this.menupath.set('External port', '/Adigem/config/snmp/external-port');
    this.menupath.set('Cloud Data', '/Adigem/config/clouddata');
    this.menupath.set('Performance', '/Adigem/config/Performance');
    this.menupath.set('CFG', '/Adigem/config/cfg');
    this.menupath.set('System', '/Adigem/config/system');

    console.log(this.menupath);
  }
}
```

and the route binding looks like:
`[routerLink]="menupath.get(item.resource)"`

I wouldn't encourage the second solution, because you will have to handle the potential case where you receive an item, which is unknown for your `menupath` map.

Also I have a concern with the `NO_ACCESS` constant that you use in your template. There is no such property of the component, so this probably breaks the compilation.